# SP2010 splistitem AND accessing css or style

Tags: css, splistitem

I have an event receiver which adds splistitems from child sites to the parents site list (in a calendar).  How do I access the css or style of an splistitem? I am wanting to color code the different child sites to make them distinguishable on the parent sites calendar.  I've been researching this for an hour and have found 0 leads.  Surely I'm not the first person to try and access the style of a listitem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SPListItem is a server object and has very little presentation logic associated with it.  However, there are a few ways to style this:

1. You could handle this by
   subclassing the control that renders the output
   and using your own control on the
   page instead of the default.
2. If the control uses Xslt to render
   the content, then you could handle
   it there by applying the css class
   during the transform.
3. if the distinguishing value can be
   determined on the client (perhaps
   something unique about the URL) then
   you could also use jQuery to find
   the items and apply the appropriate
   class.  The downside about this
   approach is that there is a quarter
   second or so lag between the page
   render and the application of the
   classes.

Comment: I may have to go with item 3 for simplicity and a tight deadline, but where can I find more information on Item 2?  Where/what event does the transform occur and how do you hook in to that event?  Many thanks!

Comment: I think XsltListViewWebPart is the best way here. You can use any data from server with ParameterBindings, and style your items any imaginable way with Xslt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand why you would want to find the style of a list item. The styles are defined by the css and all of them would have the same class applied unless you have some custom styling using either custom css, custom master pages, or themes. Why not make it part of your event that you include some metadata around which child site the event is being copied from and then add a calculated column that will color code the item?

Comment: That is precisely what I am trying to do.  Depending on which site the event is firing from I want to add a custom css class or if possible backcolor to the splistitem. How do you access this property?

Comment: You'd have to set something up like in the event receiver to set a metadata field or something indicating the site. Then you can use some of the ideas here: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-color-coded-calendar-the-payroll-schedule.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but your not answering the right question. I know how to get the current site (through the SPItemEventProperties object). However I do not know how to access the splistitem css attribute.

Comment: As Dave points out below, getting the class of the item will not help you much, as each item is not given a separate class, you have to find a unique value to that item. Once you have determined the unique value, you would need to write something that would apply conditional formatting to the item, such as JQuery or some other css method.